# Can I pass two arrays through Ajax to controller. (File Array and Int Array)

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, model-view-controller

I am using below code for collecting data and Ajax call:

```
            var childArr = [];
            var File_Arr = [];
            File_Arr = $('#File_Arr');
            console.log($.type(File_Arr));
            $('#File_Arr').each(function () {
                File_Arr.push($(this).val());
            });
            //File_Arr = $("#File_Arr").val();
            var children = $('#file-container table').children('tbody');
            var test1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
            var test2 = [5, 6, 7, 8];
            $(children).each(function (index, item) {
                var count = $(item).children().length - 1;
                childArr.push(count);
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Content("~/Search_Replace_/UploadFile")",
                type: "POST",
                data: {'tableRowCount':childArr,'File_Arr':File_Arr},
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                charset: "utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    console.log('Success!');
                }
            });
```

and I am using below code in controller to catch both the arrays:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(int[] tableRowCount, HttpPostedFileBase[] File_Arr)
```

but here I am only able to get `File_Arr` properly and `tableRowCount` is coming as `null`.

Please note: I have also tried `JSON.stringify()` method, but that is showing the error of Maximum Call stack size exceeded.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use form data to send files with data. Try this:

```
    var childArr = [];

    var fileUploadControl = $('#File_Arr').get(0);

    var files = fileUploadControl.files;

    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('File_Arr', files[i]);
    }

    var children = $('#file-container table').children('tbody');
    var test1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var test2 = [5, 6, 7, 8];
    $(children).each(function (index, item) {
        var count = $(item).children().length - 1;
        childArr.push(count);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < childArr.length; i++) {
        formData.append('tableRowCount', childArr[i]);
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Content("~/Search_Replace_/UploadFile")",
        type : "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log('Success!');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, can you also tell me how I can access this data in controller?

Comment: With the same code you have written in your controller. No changes!

Comment: I tried to access it but tableRowCount is still coming as null in controller. Do I have to  use Request['tableRowCount'] to maybe access it in controller?

Comment: Check whether your **childArr** has data. Yes you can access it from the **Request** object but then we don't need to specify the parameters in the action method.

Comment: I checked using debugger in jquery, childArr has data in it, but still getting null in controller.

Comment: Got both the values in action method see the link https://ibb.co/cxzfy10 by using the same code. Inspect your form data object.

Comment: I have put the script tag where all this code resides before the @Html.BeginForm. Can this cause any error?

Comment: I have also added both the arrays in the model as well.

model code as below:

public HttpPostedFileBase[] File_Arr { get; set; }
        public int [] tableRowCount { get; set; }

Comment: Is this ajax request is separate from the form submission? If so, then you can give id to your button and call this ajax request on its click handler. if this is not the case then why you are not posting it via form? Second thing, if you are using the model as a parameter then it won't work we need to pass parameter with the same name as you have in backend. So, you need to pass your model in form data object.

Comment: I am calling the ajax call on button click of the submit button of the form If there is a better way please let me know. Also, I have the same names in model as well. Should I pass model as object itself?

Comment: You can choose either form submission or ajax call. For ajax, you need to change the button type to button like this `<button type="button">`, call ajax function on its on click handler and follow the above code for both the client and backend. let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi, I am little confused about the linking part, Can we connect via email. 

Email: hiteshjeswani112@gmail.com

Comment: @hiteshJeswani Sure.